# Removing Email Address Required Field for Anonymous Users in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I have an email address field that shows up at the top of my commerce checkout form for anonymous users. It's a required field. However I've added my own email address field to the form further down the page in the billing information area. I don't want the account information fieldset and associated email address field at all because only anonymous users use the site.

Does anyone know where I can find this email address field...is it in views somewhere? I'd just hide the whole fieldset but the field is required so I need to actually remove it from the code somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Account info section by dragging it to disable section by visiting page 'admin/commerce/config/checkout'.

As in the screenshot Account Information is in Disabled instead of Checkout which is default configuration.
[image]

But remember there is a default rule which tries to create an account for anonymous user using the email id, you might have to disable it, or may have to turn in conditional.

Comment: thanks that worked well. Can you explain more what you mean about your last sentence re: default rules?

Comment: nothing major, I meant go to 'admin/config/workflow/rules' and see what all rules you need actually, as an example rule with title 'Create a new account for an anonymous order'' will throw a warning since it will not find an email id.

Comment: You also need to check your confirmation email rules. In the case of Commerce Message, the rules use the Account email address when generating the email confirmation to the customer.